# android progressbar indeterminate horizontal

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I would like to create a horizontal indeterminate progressbar such as showed [in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPQk.png) Is it possible to create it with `drawable` defined in `xml` (eg. animated-list) ?

Two variants:

- red rectangle goes always from left to right
- red rectangle goes from left to right and then it returns back to left

layout / my_layout.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate"/>
```

drawable / `progressbar_indeterminate.xml`